# Display nested json objects in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I want to display the incoming messages on a webpage. I have a url pointing to a JSON-file, the data looks like this ...

```
[
    {
      "created_at": "2019-06-08T10:30:52Z",
      "data": {
        "name": "Me",
        "email": "me@example.com",
        "is-org-bedrijf": "on",
        "org-bedrijf": "",
        "onderwerp": "meer info",
        "bericht": "bericht",
        "job-logo-deadline": "",
        "digitaal-deadline": "",
        "drukwerk-deadline": "",
        "flex-floc-kleuren": "transparant",
        "job-flex-floc-deadline": "",
        "andere-beschrijving": "",
        "andere-deadline": "",
        "g-recaptcha-response": ""
      },
      "folder": null,
      "id": 3250210,
      "referrer": "https://lennertderyck.be/contact/form",
      "request_ip": "78.23.211.248",
      "spam": null
    }
]
```

How can i access the information in a javascript loop? Displaying the data is not the problem, it's accessing the data in the nested object.

This is what I tried

```
 fetch('file.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (source) {
                appendData(source);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(source) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0, il = source.length; i < il; i++) {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = 'Id: ' + source[i].id;
                    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                for (var j = 0; jl = source[i].data.length; j++) {
                    console.log(source[i].data[j].name)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not how you iterate through an object. Do it with a `for...in` loop like so:

```
for (var item in source[i].data) {
    console.log(source[i].data[item].name);
}
```

Comment: Now i just get 14 times undefined in the console. But when I remove name, and just use source[i].data[item] all the data is shown correctly.